# Audio output not working

Tags: audio, pi-3b+, lakka

I bought a raspberry pi3b+ for my son that is connected to the TV, I installed both raspian and  lakka and i configure it, but there is no sound coming from the TV via the HDMI port.

After several try i been able to have sound when using raspian by forcing the sound to output via hdmi   with the sudo raspi-config command.
I also discovered that the sound was set to low by default so i put it on max to be able to control it with my tv controler.

The problem is that when i boot lakka, there is still no sound...  but if i plug an audio jack like computer speaker i have sound. Is there a way to for lakka to play via the hdmi too?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot?

Comment: Also remember to use gui desktop top right hand corner speaker icon RIGHT click and select HDMI.

Comment: You have given many important information in your comments. Please edit your question and add the information to it. It would be a good idea to take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).